# When using the render helper, the model is not found

Tags: ember.js

I have the following line of code in a template:

```
{{render 'hire_us.startups' hireUsStartups}}
```

It is able to find the view which is called `App.HireUsStartupsView` but it can't find the model which is called `App.HireUsStartups`.  I checked the console to make sure that `App.HireUsStartups` is being defined and it is.  Also, I don't have a controller defined in case that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the model is what you pass in as the second argument, so the model here is `hireUsStartups`